# In Excel how can I return the address of a cell based on the value in a sheet without previously limiting to a certain column or row?

Tags: excel

[image]

In my example above I have a 4 by 3 table and I want the cell address of T but I do not know in which row or column of the 4 by 3 table the value could be located just that it is within the table. What excel formula will return the address? Assume there are too many rows and columns to use if functions to search one row or column at a time with a series of if then statements. All values within the table are unique

Comment: What do you want to do with this address?

Comment: I have another sheet with values corresponding to each letter arranged in the same manner and I will use this address combined with the other sheet's name to output the value I want (ex. T is located in cell C3 on sheet 1 so I want to output sheet 2 C3 value)

Comment: then getting the actual address is the long way around.  Another question: are the values unique in the grid?

Comment: Yes all values are unique

Answer (score 1):

use INDEX and skip getting the address:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:D3)/(A1:D3="t"),1),AGGREGATE(15,7,COLUMN(A1:D3)/(A1:D3="t"),1))
```

A couple of notes:

1. The INDEX range (`Sheet2!A:D` in my example) should always start in column A even if the data is in different column and should include the full columns to the end of the data set in the other sheet.
2. The other ranges (`A1:D3` in my example) should be limited to the search range's actual address.

[image]